# Why are user address fields required

Tags: users

I am trying to figure out a plugin or something to change the address, city, state, and country fields so they are NOT required fields.  Please point me in the correct direction.

If the only solution is to directly modify PHP I will need a detail explanation because I am not familiar with the PHP or the framework.

Comment: WordPress doesn't have address/city/state fields, is this a custom plugin?

Comment: @TomJNowell you are probably onto something here. They might be there because I am using Events Manager Pro and Stripe. I can see address required for payment but not for the general user..

Comment: The issue here was Events Manager Pro related payment gateway fields. If a related field payment gateway field is selected in the Events Manager Pro it becomes a required field on the user profile page.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for this post. I had same issue caused by Event Manager Pro. The resolution for me was to go to the Forms Editor in Event Manager Pro and change a few "common" fields to not required.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I had the same issue. It seems like bug that that setting in Events Manager Pro makes the fields on the user's profile mandatory, not just on an Events Manager booking form.

Comment: Running into this again! To clarify, in Events Manager Forms Editor, scroll down to the "User Fields" and uncheck those that you don't want to make "required."